# Area of a trapezoid with perpendicular diagonals, embedded in a triangle

Tags: geometry, area

Let $ABED$ be a trapezoid as in

[image: this figure]

If $AB \parallel DE$, $AE \perp BD$, $AB = 10$, $DE = 4$ and $\angle ACB = 45°$, what's the area of $ABED$?

I must also mention that this is for an elementary geometry course, so I have restricted myself to that approach --I have not attempted anything related to calculus or analytic geometry for the same reason.

I have tried the following: (1) Using triangle similarity to get the height of the trapezoid (2) Using sine or cosine law to the same end (3) Trying to get the length of its diagonals with similar approaches as above (4) Using some weird formula for the area of a triangle by multiplying its three sides and dividing it by the circunradius. None of the above worked. Every time I get equations with more than one variable, and can't figure out a way to get a system that would help me solve them.

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: ABDE has questionable form according to your picture, verify your letters, please

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Or are you not sure how to begin the problem?

Comment: The first thing you know is that triangles ABF and DEF are **similar**.

Comment: I have tried the following:
(1) Using triangle similarity to get the height of the trapezoid
(2) Using sine or cosine law to the same end
(3) Trying to get the length of its diagonals with similar approaches as above
(4) Using some weird formula for the area of a triangle by multiplying its three sides and dividing it by the circunradius.

None of the above worked. Every time I get equations with more than one variable, and can't figure out a way to get a system that would help me solve them.

Comment: I dunno if this is intended solution, but I couldn't help but go with 4 equations, which involved cosine theorem etc, which solved into 140/3 ...
If this is correct, I'll post my solution.
Gonna be honest, that 45 angle on top felt so hard to deal with for some reason, unless I'm forgetting something super elementary, I strongly believe that something is wrong with the given info.

Comment: @Makina I also think something's wrong with the given information, but cannot pinpoint what exactly. In any case, I don't have the actual solution, but could you post yours? I'd really like to take a look into your reasoning.

Comment: Sure, posted my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so using the fact, that many triangles are congruent, I constructed this:

[image]

Now:

$x^2 + y^2 = 4$ (1)

$4z^2 + 4m^2 - 4*\sqrt{2}mz = 16 => mz = \frac{z^2+m^4 -4}{\sqrt{2}}$ (2)

$4y^2 +25x^2 = 9m^2$ (3)

$4x^2 + 25y^2 = 9z^2$ (4)

---

Add up (3) and (4), then replace $z^2 + m^2$ in (2) and calculate $mz = \frac{40*\sqrt{2}}{9}$

Now, using the area formula, which involves sinus: $S = S_{big} - S_{small} = 0.5*25*mz*\sin{45} - 0.5*4*mz*\sin{45} = \frac{0.5*21*40*\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}*9} = \frac{140}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

The hint.

Let $FE=x$, $DF=y$, $L\in AB$ such that $DL||EB.$

Thus, $$x^2+y^2=16,$$
$$AF=2.5x,$$ $$BF=2.5y$$ and since $DL=EB$, $AL=10-4=6$ and $\measuredangle ADL=45^{\circ},$ by low of cosines we obtain:
$$AD^2+LD^2-2AD\cdot LD\cos45^{\circ}=AL^2$$ or
$$6.25x^2+y^2+6.25y^2+x^2-2\sqrt{(6.25x^2+y^2)(6.25y^2+x^2)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=36.$$
After solving of this system use $$S_{ABED}=\frac{1}{2}AE\cdot DB.$$

I got $xy=\frac{160}{21}$ and $S_{ABED}=\frac{140}{3}.$

Comment: Why is $\measuredangle ALD=45^{\circ}$?

Comment: @user24142 It was typo. Thank you! I fixed.

Comment: Still not seeing it sorry.

Comment: ohhh, that's a given, my bad...

Answer (score -1):

If $\measuredangle FAB=\theta^{\circ}$ then $AE = 14 \cos \theta$, $DB = 14 \sin \theta$, and the area we require is $98 \sin \theta \cos \theta$. I can furthermore construct such a diagram for any $\theta$ (construct $AB$ then $F$ then $E$, $D$ and $C$).

The problem is underspecified.

eta: Apologies, I was not seeing the other part of the specification. The angle at $C$ is given. That makes the problem solvable.